# Watch for changes in any attribute on component element

Tags: angular

Is there anyway in angular4 to watch for changes in any of the attribute on component element? The reason why I want this is that there is group of attributes called aria attributes which are part of [Web Accessibility Initiative](https://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/accessibility) and when creating custom components you need to be able to path through those attributes from you component's tag to some element in your template (for example input). I do not want to use `@Input` because there is a lot of those attributes and i do not want to create `@Input` for each of them also there is a naming issues as well. I have been thinking about creating some custom service which will watch for changes in any of aria attributes and provide object with those attributes (probably as Observables) to component so it can use it in its template. I was looking at [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) API but I would like to know if there is any angular native way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Angular material team had the same issue a while ago. The initial matInput was just a regular angular component. But they had to create a lot of @inputs to allow users to bind to all native input properties.

```
<mat-input></mat-input>
```

They solved it by splitting the input component into two separate pieces. The container element (regular) component, and matInput directive. Users are responsible for transcluding the native input component and attaching the matInput directive on the native element.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput />
<mat-form-field>
```

So if you want to create a specialized input component I suggest you use the same approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i think this approach may not work in my case - components can be pretty complicated and you might want to pass attributes on different elements which are located in different places of template so transclude won't help